# Class policy with gpu/cpu module from OpenCV

Tags: c++, python, opencv

I want to create a class (struct) which act in different way if the gpu module from OpenCV is successfully installed or not. 
For example, if gpu module is intalled i would use `gpu::meanShitFiltering` else `cv::pyrMeanShiftFiltering`.
Here an example:

```
template <typename ComputingPolicy>
struct Computing : public ComputingPolicy
{
    //virtual void filter(PyObject *, int, int) = 0;
    //TODO: add basic exceptionhandling on range spatial and array object
};


struct CpuComputing
{
    PyObject *ExceptionHandling(){//TODO: add specific exception for pyrMeanShiftfiltering
    }
    void filter(cv::Mat src, cv::Mat dst, int r, int s)
    {
        cv::pyrMeanShiftFiltering(src, dst, r, s);
    }
};

struct GpuComputing
{
    PyObject *ExceptionHandling(){//TODO: add specific exception for meanshiftfiltering
    }
    void filter(cv::Mat src, cv::Mat dst, int r, int s)
    {
        cv::gpu::GpuMat d_dst(src);
        cv::gpu::GpuMat d_src(src);
        cv::gpu::meanShiftFiltering(d_src, d_dst, r, s);
        d_dst.download(dst);
    }

};


#ifdef MACRO_INDICATING_GPU_MODULE_FROM_OPENCV_AVAILABLE
typedef Computing<GpuComputing> meanshift;
#else
typedef Computing<CpuComputing> meanshift;
#endif
```

The purpose is to use the same function on gpu or cpu if the MACRO indicate that the module is installed or not.

Is there some kind of MACRO (function opencv or variable, flags ...) like this? 
Is it a good way to create a policy class (struct) like that for my purpose?

Thanks

PS:
The purpose is to bind this cpp into python module.

Comment: One option is to use cmake. Check if the platform has gpu modules during configuration stage and create some "config.h" file where MACRO_INDICATING_GPU_MODULE_FROM_OPENCV_AVAILABLE is defined and include this file in your .cpp files, then compile

Comment: It's a way thank you but I have to compile with cmake. Any other ideas ? (it's possible to change code if necessary)